# Karate: How to check if any of the configured headers are missing

Tags: testing, karate

I've configured a set of headers to be used for every request in Karate in the background section.

```
* configure headers = { header1, header2, header3, header4 }
```

I'd like to create scenarios where each of the headers is missing.

Is there any way to create **just one scenario** to handle this particular case?
I don't want to create 4 different scenarios to check for each header.